# Creating a directory in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I am trying to create a directory using SQL Server 2017. I have enabled and reconfigured `xp_cmdshell`.

On my output I am getting an error

> Access is denied

I am using Windows authentication and this same user has been able to create databases etc.

This is what my code looks like.

```
declare @cmdpath nvarchar(100),
        @Location nvarchar(100)

set @Location = '\\LAPTOP-REGHARDT\Users\Reghardt\Documents\New%20folder'
select @Location

set @cmdpath = 'MD ' + @Location
select @cmdpath

exec xp_cmdshell @cmdpath
```

Where can I look for the required access? I have looked at the login roles? Can the issue be there?

Comment: Are you a sysadmin role member? In that case, make sure the SQL Server service account has permissions to the share and directories.

Answer (score 0):

the user which executes this script does not have permission on the shared folder in order to create folder. The error is related with OS level file/folder permissions

Comment: I am the owner of that folder. Which is my Windows Login.

Comment: are you connection to SQL Server with same login?